# How to add Back Button without using AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, back-button, appbar

I wanted to add a back button on my appBar and wanted to make the appBar transparent so that it shows only the back button.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simran, this is a little tricky but it is possible with the combination of `Stack`, `SingleChildScrollView` and `AppBar`. Here is quick example demonstrating this,

```
return Scaffold(
              body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,// Your screen background color
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(height: 70.0),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                      buildRow('This is test row.'),
                    ])
                ),
                new Positioned(
                  top: 0.0,
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: AppBar(
                    title: Text(''),// You can add title here
                    leading: new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.grey),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3), //You can make this transparent
                    elevation: 0.0, //No shadow
                  ),),
              ]),
              );
```

[image: demo]

Note: You can make the `AppBar` completely transparent. However, you'll need to design your widgets accordingly to make sure back button is visible. In the example above, i just set the opacity.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This solved my problem as of November 2021. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Just **WRAP** your widget into a **Stack** and then add an **IconButton** on top of the Stack and **Navigator.pop(context)** on button **onPressed()**. 
That should solve your problem.

```
return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    children: <Widget>[
      YourScrollViewWidget(),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )
    ],
  );
```

Comment: This doesn’t let me press and scroll the scroll view. Any other recommendation?

Comment: did u try adding the fit property of the stack as StackFit.loose ??

Comment: or try Wrapping up the Icon into Align widget and give alignment as Alignment.topLeft